# adding single points to bar figure in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a bar plot, in which I would like to add some single points overlayed on the bars. Those points are in another scale compared to the error bars. Below, I'm illustrating those single points in green. Note that, I would like also to add an entry in the figure's legend referring to those points. Ideally the points should be centered in the middle of each pair of bars.
I was having some difficulties in changing the range of the second y-axis (`units`), it's displayed in the range `[0,1]` but would like to have it ideally in the range `[1,5]`. Is it also possible to add a label for each single point? Any suggestions and improvements on the `latex` code are welcom ;-)
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [align=center, font=\small, rotate=45,
text width=2.15cm, inner sep=0.25cm] at (0.6cm, -0.65cm) {\textsc{year 1}};

\node [align=center, font=\small, rotate=45,
text width=2.15cm, inner sep=0.25cm] at (2.90cm, -0.65cm) {\textsc{year 2}};

\node [align=center,font=\small, rotate=45,
text width=2.15cm, inner sep=0.25cm] at (5.30cm, -0.73cm) {\textsc{year 3}};

\begin{axis}[
    title style={align=center, yshift=-0.35em},
    ybar,
    ymin={60}, ymax={93.5},
    width={8cm}, height={5cm},
    bar width={7pt},
    ticks=both,
    ytick={60,70,80,90,100.0},
    ylabel style={yshift=-0.65em},
    ylabel={Percent},
    ymajorgrids,
    nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill, precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=0.25mm},
    xtick = data,
    table/header=false,
    table/row sep=\\,
    xticklabels={},
    enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper},
    legend style={font=\tiny},
    %legend pos=north west
    %legend style={at={(0.5, 1.20)}, anchor=north, legend columns=2},
    legend style={at={(0.5, -0.52)}, anchor=north, legend columns=2},
]
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{89.17\\71.71\\81.41\\};
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{70.60\\64.11\\84.92\\};
\draw (axis cs:0.52,0) -- ({axis cs:0.52,0}|-{rel axis cs:0.5,1});
\draw (axis cs:1.49,0) -- ({axis cs:1.49,0}|-{rel axis cs:0.5,1});
\draw (axis cs:2.50,0) -- ({axis cs:2.50,0}|-{rel axis cs:0.5,1});
\legend{\textsc{Prod 1}\hspace*{8pt}, \textsc{Prod 2} }
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    axis y line*={right},
    axis x line={none},
    ymin={1}, ymax={5},
    width={8cm}, height={5cm},
    ylabel style={yshift=0.60em},
    ylabel={units},
    ytick={1,2,3,4,5}
]
% add points here?
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can plot those circles like

```
\begin{axis}[
    axis y line*={right},
    axis x line={none},
    ymin={1}, ymax={5},
    width={8cm}, height={5cm},
    ylabel style={xshift=0.60em},
    ylabel={units},
]
\addplot[only marks,mark=*,mark size=3pt,green,
         nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,
                                    precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        point meta=y,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=0.25mm},
        ]  coordinates {
    (1,3.5) (2,4) (3,2)
};
\end{axis}
```

and add

```
\addlegendimage{draw=green,fill=green!30}
\addlegendentry{\textsc{Legend}}
```

to add the extra legend. You have to make `legend columns=3` additionally.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [align=center, font=\small, rotate=45,
text width=2.15cm, inner sep=0.25cm] at (0.6cm, -0.65cm) {\textsc{year 1}};

\node [align=center, font=\small, rotate=45,
text width=2.15cm, inner sep=0.25cm] at (2.90cm, -0.65cm) {\textsc{year 2}};

\node [align=center,font=\small, rotate=45,
text width=2.15cm, inner sep=0.25cm] at (5.30cm, -0.73cm) {\textsc{year 3}};

\begin{axis}[
    title style={align=center, yshift=-0.35em},
    ybar,
    ymin={60}, ymax={93.5},
    width={8cm}, height={5cm},
    bar width={7pt},
    ticks=both,
    ytick={60,70,80,90,100.0},
    ylabel style={yshift=-0.65em},
    ylabel={Percent},
    ymajorgrids,
    nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill, precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=0.25mm},
    xtick = data,
    table/header=false,
    table/row sep=\\,
    xticklabels={},
    enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper},
    legend style={font=\tiny},
    %legend pos=north west
    %legend style={at={(0.5, 1.20)}, anchor=north, legend columns=2},
    legend style={at={(0.5, -0.52)}, anchor=north, legend columns=3},
]
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{89.17\\71.71\\81.41\\};
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{70.60\\64.11\\84.92\\};
\draw (axis cs:0.52,0) -- ({axis cs:0.52,0}|-{rel axis cs:0.5,1});
\draw (axis cs:1.49,0) -- ({axis cs:1.49,0}|-{rel axis cs:0.5,1});
\draw (axis cs:2.50,0) -- ({axis cs:2.50,0}|-{rel axis cs:0.5,1});
\legend{\textsc{Prod 1}\hspace*{8pt}, \textsc{Prod 2}}
\addlegendimage{draw=green,fill=green!30}
\addlegendentry{\textsc{Legend}}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    axis y line*={right},
    axis x line={none},
    ymin={1}, ymax={5},
    width={8cm}, height={5cm},
    ylabel style={xshift=0.60em},
    ylabel={units},
]
\addplot[only marks,mark=*,mark size=3pt,green,
         nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,
                                    precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        point meta=y,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=0.25mm},
        ]  coordinates {
    (1,3.5) (2,4) (3,2)
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to show circles only at some points, better draw them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [align=center, font=\small, rotate=45,
text width=2.15cm, inner sep=0.25cm] at (0.6cm, -0.65cm) {\textsc{year 1}};

\node [align=center, font=\small, rotate=45,
text width=2.15cm, inner sep=0.25cm] at (2.90cm, -0.65cm) {\textsc{year 2}};

\node [align=center,font=\small, rotate=45,
text width=2.15cm, inner sep=0.25cm] at (5.30cm, -0.73cm) {\textsc{year 3}};

\begin{axis}[
    title style={align=center, yshift=-0.35em},
    ybar,
    ymin={60}, ymax={93.5},
    width={8cm}, height={5cm},
    bar width={7pt},
    ticks=both,
    ytick={60,70,80,90,100.0},
    ylabel style={yshift=-0.65em},
    ylabel={Percent},
    ymajorgrids,
    nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill, precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=0.25mm},
    xtick = data,
    table/header=false,
    table/row sep=\\,
    xticklabels={},
    enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper},
    legend style={font=\tiny},
    %legend pos=north west
    %legend style={at={(0.5, 1.20)}, anchor=north, legend columns=2},
    legend style={at={(0.5, -0.52)}, anchor=north, legend columns=3},
]
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{89.17\\71.71\\81.41\\};
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{70.60\\64.11\\84.92\\};
\draw (axis cs:0.52,0) -- ({axis cs:0.52,0}|-{rel axis cs:0.5,1});
\draw (axis cs:1.49,0) -- ({axis cs:1.49,0}|-{rel axis cs:0.5,1});
\draw (axis cs:2.50,0) -- ({axis cs:2.50,0}|-{rel axis cs:0.5,1});
%\fill[green] (axis cs:0,85) circle(3pt) node [right,rotate=90] {85};
\fill[green] (axis cs:1,90) circle(3pt) node [right,rotate=90] {90};
\fill[green] (axis cs:2,70) circle(3pt) node [right,rotate=90] {70};
\legend{\textsc{Prod 1}\hspace*{8pt}, \textsc{Prod 2}}
\addlegendimage{draw=green,fill=green!30}
\addlegendentry{\textsc{Legend}}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    axis y line*={right},
    axis x line={none},
    ymin={1}, ymax={5},
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    width={8cm}, height={5cm},
    ylabel style={xshift=0.60em},
    ylabel={units},
]
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @@Haris Kumar, thanks for your reply! Is it possible to display a label for each green dot? For instance for the first dot, I would like to display '3.5' in top of it, for the second '4' (i.e the `y`-coordinate value). Similar to the numbers on top of the bars.

Comment: @Tin Like that? Answer updated.

Comment: @@Harish Kumar, thanks! One last question. If I remove the first green dot, and plot only the last 2 ones, then it seems to be that the x-axis gets somehow spread and the remaining 2 green points don't stay where they should, they move accordingly. could you please have a look?

Comment: @Tin Please see the update, too tired now for explanations.